How to measure the error on extrapolation from a double log fit?
I am writing residual gas analysis mass spectrometry software in Python. One of the functions of this software is to take the raw mass spec intensity data, $y$, and timestamps $t$, and fit them to the following double natural log function:
$y = a \ln(pt) - b \ln(qt)$
where $a \ln(pt)$ represents the ingrowth of gases from memory, and $-b \ln(qt)$ represents consumption by ionization from the mass spec.
The goal of fitting these data is to determine the $t=0$ intercept, however, obviously $\ln(0)$ cannot be evaluated. The solution is to shift the timestamps by 30 seconds, which accounts for the 30 second gas equilibration period before the measurements and timestamps start; therefore, the "intercept" is found by evaluating the function with shifted timestamps at $t=30$. Let's call this not-really-a-true-intercept intensity $y_0$.
Finding the best fit parameters and solving the function for $y_0$ at $t=30$ is trivial, however, the error is where I have problems: admittedly, I am a bit out of my depth here, so any guidance would be appreciated.
Here's what I've tried:
Calculating the error on $y_0$, $\sigma_{y_{0}}$, as the sum, in quadrature, of the standard deviation of the residuals on the fit, plus the error on the extrapolation to $y_0$ estimated by bootstrapping.
$\sigma_{y_{0}} = \sqrt{\sigma_{\text{residuals}}^2 + \sigma_{\text{bootstrap}}^2}$
The first term, the standard deviation of the residuals, is trivially easy to determine. The second term, however, never converges so that the error is different every time it's calculated.
Here is the Python code: I am randomly resampling $t$ and $y$, fitting an intercept to the resampled data, and returning the standard deviation of those intercepts.
import math
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model


def double_ln_func(t, a, b, p, q):
    return a * np.log(p * t) - b * np.log(q * t)


def bootstrap_double_ln_fit(t, y, model, params, n=10000):
    # bootstrap the fit
    results = [] # store the intercept values
    old_result_std = np.inf
    for i in range(n):
        # randomly sample the data with replacement
        indices  = np.random.choice(range(len(y)), len(y), replace=True)
        y_sample = y[indices]
        t_sample = t[indices]
        
        # fit the sampled data
        bresult = model.fit(y_sample, params, t=t_sample, nan_policy='omit')
        results.append(double_ln_func(30, **bresult.best_values))

        # calculate the standard deviation of the bootstrapping results
        new_result_std  = np.std(results)
        # check if the standard deviation has converged
        if i > 20 and abs((new_result_std - old_result_std) / old_result_std) < 1e-6:
            break
        else:
            old_result_std = new_result_std

    # calculate the bootstrap error
    intercept_error = np.std(results)
    
    return intercept_error


def double_ln_fit(t, y, return_error):
    # scale y to make the fitting process more stable
    y_oom    = math.floor(math.log10(np.abs(y.max()))) # y order of magnitude
    y_scf    = 10 ** y_oom # y scaling factor for re-scaling results
    y_scaled = y * 10 ** -y_oom # scale y to ~1

    # offset the t values by 30 seconds to account for gas equilibration time
    t_shifted = t + 30

    # create the model and set the initial parameters
    model  = Model(double_ln_func)
    params = model.make_params(a=1, b=1, p=5, q=0.1)
    params['p'].set(min=1e-20)
    params['q'].set(min=1e-20)
    
    # fit the data to the double nat log function
    result = model.fit(y_scaled, params, t=t_shifted, nan_policy='omit')
    
    # get the fitted values for plotting
    fitted_t = np.linspace(min(t_shifted), max(t_shifted), 100)
    fitted_y = double_ln_func(fitted_t, **result.best_values)
    
    # re-scale the fitted values
    fitted_t = fitted_t - 30
    fitted_y = fitted_y * y_scf
    
    # get the intercept from the best fit values
    intercept = double_ln_func(30, **result.best_values) * y_scf
    
    # if we need to return the error calculation (function called from raw_stats_calc.py)
    if return_error:
        # calculate the residuals of the fit
        residuals = y_scaled - double_ln_func(t_shifted, **result.best_values)
        resid_std = np.std(residuals)
    
        # get the error from bootstrapping the fit
        bootstrap_err = bootstrap_double_ln_fit(t_shifted, y_scaled, model, params)
    
        # calculate the error in the intercept as the sum of the residuals and bootstrap error
        intercept_err = np.sqrt(resid_std**2 + bootstrap_err**2) * y_scf
    
    # if no error is required (function is called from plot_raw_data.py), just return nan
    else:
        intercept_err = np.nan
    
    return [fitted_t, fitted_y], intercept, intercept_err


I've also tried calculating the partial derivatives of the equation, and using these in conjunction with the variance of each term from the covariance matrix pcov returned by curve_fit, however, curve_fit often fails to find pcov when the data are highly scattered, so I can't rely on this.
Perhaps a different means of calculating the error would be more appropriate for these data?
Here are some sample data that can be passed to the double ln fit function:
He 3798 Q1520_  2024-06-25T09:49:42 
time_sec    2 amu   3 amu   4 amu   40 amu
2.691   1.918947E-9 1.353086E-9 1.083636E-9 2.424798E-11
8.393   1.924420E-9 1.352441E-9 1.081825E-9 2.451031E-11
13.995  1.924468E-9 1.350765E-9 1.082597E-9 2.493171E-11
19.595  1.925282E-9 1.349962E-9 1.081301E-9 2.494261E-11
25.195  1.927887E-9 1.349370E-9 1.080510E-9 2.491214E-11
30.895  1.930570E-9 1.348243E-9 1.079783E-9 2.517592E-11
36.495  1.932480E-9 1.347466E-9 1.079611E-9 2.510602E-11
42.095  1.931847E-9 1.348131E-9 1.079237E-9 2.513002E-11
47.795  1.934760E-9 1.346782E-9 1.078437E-9 2.512803E-11
53.395  1.929853E-9 1.345735E-9 1.078367E-9 2.498039E-11
58.996  1.934834E-9 1.345541E-9 1.077280E-9 2.520110E-11
64.596  1.932654E-9 1.344552E-9 1.077504E-9 2.550219E-11

and again in a more convenient format:
t   = [2.691, 8.393, 13.995, 19.595, 25.195, 30.895, 36.495, 42.095, 47.795, 53.395, 58.996, 64.596]
y2  = [1.918947e-09, 1.924420e-09, 1.924468e-09, 1.925282e-09, 1.927887e-09, 1.930570e-09, 1.932480e-09, 1.931847e-09, 1.934760e-09, 1.929853e-09, 1.934834e-09, 1.932654e-09]
y3  = [1.353086e-09, 1.352441e-09, 1.350765e-09, 1.349962e-09, 1.349370e-09, 1.348243e-09, 1.347466e-09, 1.348131e-09, 1.346782e-09, 1.345735e-09, 1.345541e-09, 1.344552e-09]
y4  = [1.083636e-09, 1.081825e-09, 1.082597e-09, 1.081301e-09, 1.080510e-09, 1.079783e-09, 1.079611e-09, 1.079237e-09, 1.078437e-09, 1.078367e-09, 1.077280e-09, 1.077504e-09]
y40 = [2.424798e-11, 2.451031e-11, 2.493171e-11, 2.494261e-11, 2.491214e-11, 2.517592e-11, 2.510602e-11, 2.513002e-11, 2.512803e-11, 2.498039e-11, 2.520110e-11, 2.550219e-11]

Here are the fits for that particular analysis from my program:

Note that these plots use the original timestamps, not the +30 shifted timestamps.
As requested, here are the standard deviations ($y$-axis) over the number of boostraps ($x$-axis) with $n=10,000$ and no convergence cutoff:
2 amu:

3 amu:

4 amu:

40 amu:

